# How can I print out all cases from a switch in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple program which uses a switch.

```
switch (value) {
  case 'hello':
    return ...
  case 'hey':
    return ...
  case 'hi':
    return ...
  case 'howdy':
    return ...
```

I am looking for a way to print all possible cases/variants of the const value in the switch. So that the value would equal the possible cases like "value=hello,hey,hi,howdy" and such. It sounds really simple yet I couldn't find any possible solution to work this out anywhere online.

Comment: Is there a reason you want/need a switch and not a lookup/map? Because then you could just do `Object.keys(myMap)` or something similar.

Comment: Your question seems to indicate you execute the code multiple times, but that context is missing. By the `return` we can guess it is a function, but where do you call it, how does it get called multiple times, and what is the scope where you want to collect this information?

Comment: edit: I am looking for a way to print all **possible** cases of the switch, not all **used**, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @IanH. I only need one true value (for the main script, that is why switch is enough) and be able to print all possible values in another script, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @trincot I edited the context, I only call it one time and I need to print all **possible** values in another script, it was a misunderstanding.

Comment: I don't understand: you have hard-coded those values, so you even know them without running the program. What is the issue with printing them?

Comment: The source code *is* the list of all possible cases. Are you asking how to do it programmatically? I guess you could parse the source code. Why do you *want* to do this? This seems like an X/Y problem, but it's difficult to tell. If you need to be able to programmatically determine what possibilities the function handles at *runtime* (without a pre-run parse or horrible shenanigans) then you need to restructure the function, like a lookup table of functions as already suggested.